# How to subtract from columns and not rows in NumPy matrices?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, transpose

I have a matrix `X`:

```
[[  2.  nan  nan  nan]
 [  3.   2.  nan  nan]
 [ nan   5.   5.  nan]
 [ nan  nan  nan  nan]]
```

And a list `b`:

```
[-1.0, 2.0, 0.5, -2.0]
```

When I do `X - b` I get:

```
[[ 3.   nan  nan  nan]
 [ 4.   0.   nan  nan]
 [ nan  3.   4.5  nan]
 [ nan  nan  nan  nan]]
```

What if I wanted to subtract `b` across columns and not rows.

I'm looking for something like `X - b.transpose()`:

```
[[ 3.   nan  nan  nan]
 [ 1.   0.   nan  nan]
 [ nan  4.5  4.5  nan]
 [ nan  nan  nan  nan]]
```

Comment: What's wrong with `X - b.transpose()`? Seems like a perfectly valid solution here.

Comment: @ajcr did you actually try that? BKS, you could convert b to an array and then use b[:, None]

Comment: @PaulPanzer: I meant the *approach* was fine (transposing a "row" vector to a "column" vector and then subtracting), not that that code would work as it was literally written.

Comment: An extended answer on why `b.transpose()` does not work, http://stackoverflow.com/a/35256816/901925

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution using [***numpy.vstack***](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html) function(to stack an array vertically):

```
a = np.array([[ 2.0,  np.NaN,  np.NaN,  np.NaN],
     [  3.0,   2.0, np.NaN,  np.NaN],
     [ np.NaN,   5.0,   5.0,  np.NaN],
     [ np.NaN,  np.NaN,  np.NaN,  np.NaN]])

b = np.array([-1.0, 2.0, 0.5, -2.0])
print(a - np.vstack(b))
```

The output:

```
[[ 3.   nan  nan  nan]
 [ 1.   0.   nan  nan]
 [ nan  4.5  4.5  nan]
 [ nan  nan  nan  nan]]
```

Comment: `vstack` is an unconventional way to turn `b` into a (4,1) array.  I'd use `b[:,np.newaxis]`.

Comment: Look at the python code for `vstack` to see why I discourage this use. It turns each element of `b` into a 2d array and then concatenates them.

Comment: @hpaulj, what is your suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

Here's one gotcha worth pointing out:

```
>>> a = np.identity(4)
>>> a
array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],                                                                                                                                
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],                                                                                                                                
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.],                                                                                                                                
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.]])                                                                                                                               
>>> b = [1,2,3,4]                                                                                                                     
>>> a-b                                                                                                                                                     
array([[ 0., -2., -3., -4.],                                                                                                                                
       [-1., -1., -3., -4.],                                                                                                                                
       [-1., -2., -2., -4.],                                                                                                                                
       [-1., -2., -3., -3.]])                                                                                                                               
>>> a-np.matrix(b)
matrix([[ 0., -2., -3., -4.],                                                                                                                               
        [-1., -1., -3., -4.],                                                                                                                               
        [-1., -2., -2., -4.],                                                                                                                               
        [-1., -2., -3., -3.]])                                                                                                                              
>>> a-np.array(b)                                                                                                                                     
array([[ 0., -2., -3., -4.],                                                                                                                                
       [-1., -1., -3., -4.],                                                                                                                                
       [-1., -2., -2., -4.],                                                                                                                                
       [-1., -2., -3., -3.]])
>>> a-np.matrix(b).T  # T is short for transpose()
matrix([[ 0., -1., -1., -1.],
        [-2., -1., -2., -2.],
        [-3., -3., -2., -3.],
        [-4., -4., -4., -3.]])
```

But:

```
>>> a-np.array(b).T
array([[ 0., -2., -3., -4.],
       [-1., -1., -3., -4.],
       [-1., -2., -2., -4.],
       [-1., -2., -3., -3.]])
```

With 1d arrays `.T` does nothing! Use instead

```
>>> a-np.array(b)[:, None]
array([[ 0., -1., -1., -1.],
       [-2., -1., -2., -2.],
       [-3., -3., -2., -3.],
       [-4., -4., -4., -3.]])
```

Comment: @hpaulj Sorry, won't happen again ;-) More seriously, I wouldn't touch `np.matrix` with a bargepole, no matter what for.

Comment: I didn't notice your `None` answer when I first commented. `matrix` has its uses, but it often confuses beginners.