# slicing. Is the result a row or a column?

Tags: numpy

I would like to know why a) returns a column, whereas b) returns a row.

a) column

```
x = np.array([[ 0,  1,  2],[ 3,  4,  5],[ 6,  7,  8],[ 9, 10, 11]]) 
z = x[0:4:1,0:1:1]
```

returns

> [[0]
>    [3]
>    [6]
>    [9]]

b) row

```
 z = x[0:4  ,0]
```

returns

> [0 3 6 9]

Comment: `z` is not a row, `z` is 1D. a row would be `r = x[0:1, :]` -> `[[0 1 2]]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do numpy 1D arrays follow row/column rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35252397/do-numpy-1d-arrays-follow-row-column-rules)

Answer (score 0):

```
In [119]: x = np.array([[ 0, 1, 2],[ 3, 4, 5],[ 6, 7, 8],[ 9, 10, 11]])
In [120]: x
Out[120]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11]])
In [121]: x.shape
Out[121]: (4, 3)
```

Indexing with a scalar, e.g `0`, picks (in this case) the first column, but returns a 1d array.  The scalar index removes a dimension.

```
In [122]: x[:,0]
Out[122]: array([0, 3, 6, 9])    # shape (4,), 1d
```

Indexing with a list returns a (4,1) array, the 1 being the size of the list:

```
In [123]: x[:,[0]]
Out[123]: 
array([[0],
       [3],
       [6],
       [9]])
```

Indexing with a slice does the same thing:

```
In [124]: x[:,0:1]
Out[124]: 
array([[0],
       [3],
       [6],
       [9]])
```

There is subtle difference, `Out[123]` is copy, `Out[124]` is a view.

When indexing with slices, each slice determines the result's dimension, in this case 4 and 1.

When indexing with scalars, that dimension is removed.

When indexing with lists, or arrays, broadcasting rules apply.

Sooner or latter you should study the indexing docs.  Pay close attention to the shape of the results:

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html