# why [] and [[]] make difference in numpy operations

Tags: python, numpy

Why I am getting different answers to the following

```
l = np.array([1,-2.6])
s = np.array([[1,-2.6]])
l = np.dot(l.T,l)
s = np.dot(s.T,s)
print l,s
```

output

```
7.76 [[ 1.   -2.6 ]
 [-2.6   6.76]]
```

Also in the following case

```
s = np.array([[ 1.,  -2.6],
 [-1.,   0.4],
 [-1.,  -0.6],
 [ 0.,   2.4],
 [ 1.,   0.4]]
)
```

print an element gives the result without [[]]

```
print s[0,:]
[1.  -2.6]
```

Comment: look at the shape for each of these

Comment: Why did you expect to get a *similar* output? `[1,-2.6]` and `[[1,-2.6]]` are not the same input, so why would you expect to get the same output?

Comment: Trasposing a 1D array makes no effect. Take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35252397/do-numpy-1d-arrays-follow-row-column-rules

Comment: In addition to @Susensio's comment, take a look at the documentation for [`dot`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html): *If both a and b are 1-D arrays, it is inner product of vectors (without complex conjugation).* *If both a and b are 2-D arrays, it is matrix multiplication, but using matmul or a @ b is preferred.*  In your example, `l` and `l.T` are 1-D, wheras `s` and `s.T` are 2-D.

Answer (score 1):

Just take a look at the shape of these objects

```
l = np.array([1,-2.6])

>>> l.shape
(2, 1)
>>> l.T.shape
(1, 2)

#  (1,2)-dim matrix * (2,1)-dim matrix = (1,1)-dim matrix
>>> np.dot(l.T, l)
7.76

s = np.array([[1,-2.6]])
>>> s.shape
(1, 2)
>>> s.T.shape
(2, 1)

# (2,1)-dim matrix * (1,2)-dim matrix = (2,2)-dim matrix
>>> np.dot(s.T,s)
[[ 1.   -2.6 ]
 [-2.6   6.76]]
```